# If $y^3-y=2x$, then $(x^2-\frac{1}{27})\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}=?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y^3-y=2x$, then $$(x^2-\frac{1}{27})\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}=?$$
The answer is given as $\frac{y}{9}$, but the approach given in the solution is more of a straightforward one, where you have to evaluate it by substituting in all the values and expanding to get the answer ( takes 10-15 lines ), I was wondering If there is a shorter and more efficient approach to this.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what approach the solution uses (it may just be that they go slowly through cancellation steps), but the obvious approach is to 1) differentiate implicitly and rearrange to find $y'$ in terms of $y$; 2) differentiate again to find $y''$ in terms of $y'$ and $y$; 3) substitute to get $y''$ in terms of $y$ only. Now you can write $x$, $y'$ and $y''$ in terms of $y$. Substitute these into the given expression and cancel.

Comment: There's nothing "sophisticated" in the above, but noticing you can write everything in terms of $y$ early on certainly helps with efficiency.

Comment: You could solve $y^{3}-y=2x$ via [Cardano's Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano's_Formula) ($1$ to $3$ lines). Then you can just plug your solution in and solve (aigan $1$ to $3$ lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch variables and write
$$-\left(x^2-\frac{1}{27}\right)\frac{x''}{[x']^3}+\frac x {x'}$$ Replace $x$ by $\frac {y^3-y}2$ and simplify.

Two lines.

Answer (score 0):

$$y^3-y=2x$$
$$(3y^2-1)dy=2dx$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{2}{3y^2-1}$$
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{-12y}{(3y^2-1)^2}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-24y}{(3y^2-1)^3}$$
Hence, $$(x^2-\dfrac{1}{27})\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \left[\dfrac{(y^3-y)^2}{4}-\dfrac{1}{27}\right]\left[\dfrac{-24y}{(3y^2-1)^3}\right]+\left(\dfrac{y^3-y}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{2}{3y^2-1}\right)$$
This can be simplified.